# Volver a la posición de un formulario después de la validación de laravel

Tags: php, laravel-9

Buenas tardes comunidad.

Tengo una validación en laravel de un formulario, que funciona correctamente. La cuestión es que el formulario esta casi al final de la pagina, y cuando vuelve con el mensaje de validación, necesito que vuelva a la posición del formulario, no al inicio de la página, ya que así el usuario no se dará cuenta si esta enviado o no. He mirado documentación y no encuentro algo similar, y antes de mover el diseño del formulario me gustaría saber si existe algo para conseguirlo. Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: Hay varias cosas que se pueden hacer, como asignar ID al formulario y usarlo en la acción, por ejemplo: `<form id="formulario" action="/ruta/#formulario" ... >`

Answer (score 0):

Buenas ya lo he solucionado, lo dejo por si a alguien le puede ayudar

Estaba usando

```
$this->validate($request,$rules,$mensajes)
```

Pero cuando volvía a la vista no bajaba al final de la misma, ya el formulario esta al final.

He cambiado el método de validación asi:

```
if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('solicitud#formulario')
        ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();;
```

Le he incluido un id al formulario, así ahora, cuando vuelve, se desplaza solo a la localizacion en la vista del formulario.